# SVN_REVISION variable not returning checkout revision in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, svn, visualsvn-server

Using Jenkins 2.138.3 and Subversion plugin on a windows machine. When doing a checkout from SVN server, SVN_REVISION environment variable isn't available as when trying to get the value all it return is empty string.

I have tried to use ${SVN_REVISION} & ${SVN_REVISION_1} but none of them return any revision number.

How can I get the SVN_REVISION number as environment variable or alternatively a simple solution to retrieve it in jenkins as a parameter?

Project type is FreeStyle project.

Edit:

Raised Issue with Jenkins [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-54849)

Comment: Which version of the SVN plugin are you using?

Comment: @Pedro Im using Subversion Plugin 2.12.1

Answer (score 1):

We ran into the same issue. Downgrade to 2.10.3, which seems to be the latest stable version.

For information, the versions after 2.10.3 but before 2.12.1 have another problem on our SVN server : the authentication fails.

Enjoy ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try your solution. 

However, regarding the downgrade... I guess, will have to do it manually as there isn't an option to downgrade it from plugins menu of Jenkins.

Comment: I have downgraded SVN plugin however it still doesn't seem to resolve my issue i.e. i still do not get the SVN revision using ${SVN_REVISION} or ${SVN_REVISION_1} variable. Any further suggestions ?

Comment: No, sorry :-( In my case, I also had a button allowing to easily downgrade using the Jenkins plugin page. Maybe it is because this version was previously installed, but not on your side.

Comment: I have tried your solution and then upgraded again which seemed to have worked for me in this instance. Also I have raised an issue with Jenkins [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-54849)